# Firestore: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions when trying to match userid to document id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My database is built in a way that each User has his own document in users collection, that document's id is equal to the users id, and inside the document there is a collection of Tasks for each user.

when i use:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works and a logged in user (i only log-in users with google provider) is able to read and write to the database, in his own collection of tasks (haven't tried writing to another user's tasks, but i assume it is possible in the given situation). But i want to restrict the users to only be able to write and read their own tasks, i tried the following:

```
    service cloud.firestore   {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.id;
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work.

a scheme of my database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpSP9.png)

any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you're doing that should be allowed, and also show that you're logging enough information to prove that the user is logged in.

Comment: Just did. thank you

Comment: Do you have an idea for me? thanks

Comment: Please update your question to also show the code for a read/write operation that you want to allow/disallow.

Comment: Could this be the problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603701/rule-for-firestore-that-enforce-user-to-write-a-document-with-id-equals-to-its-o