# Rule for Firestore that enforce user to write a document with id equals to its own uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to guarantee that an user can only add a document that has the same id that its auth.uid.

For example, an user with id 1X0T6xC6hhRN5H02zLCN6SQtwby2 can only create/update the document /salesmen/1X0T6xC6hhRN5H02zLCN6SQtwby2 .

At app level, it's done by the following command (both for create and update).

```
 this.db
    .collection("salesmen")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set(data)
    .then(function() { //...
```

At Firestore level, I am trying the following rule, but it's not working (it results in *Error writing document:  Error: Missing or insufficient permissions*.).

```
match /salesmen/{salesman} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && resource.id == request.auth.uid;
}
```

How can this rule be enforced ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`resource.id` can only be used to refer to an existing document in Firestore.  It doesn't work if the document being written doesn't exist yet.

Instead, you can use the `salesman` wildcard in your match expression to determine if the user can write a particular document, even if it doesn't exist yet:

```
match /salesmen/{salesman} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && salesman == request.auth.uid;
}
```

It looks like you can also use `request.resource.id` to reference the id of the document that possibly has not been written yet:

```
match /salesmen/{salesman} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Though I can't find that explicitly discussed in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/) as of this moment.